# How to modify macro LLVMToolchainPrebuiltRoot in VS2017?

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

When I compile my Android native library within VS 2017, here is what it displays:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MyNativeAndroid, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>ANDROID_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25
1>ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3
1>JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
1>NDK_ROOT=C:\\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b
```

None of these variables are defined in my system environment.

I need to update NDK_ROOT to be set to `C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-17b`.

It appears I need to update a global macro `$(LLVMToolchainPrebuiltRoot)` for this purpose.  This macro is also being used by C++ include path.

How does one modify this macro?

Answer (score 0):

You can modifiy part of the $(LLVMToolchainPrebuiltRoot), macro by setting the ndk path (which is what you want in your case), by going to:

**Tools->Options->Cross Platform->C++->Android**

Then change the Android NDK path to your ndk path (in your case: C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-17b)